# Is there a way to set out notifications when a TFS Service Web hook event fails or there is any change in State of the web hook

Tags: azure, tfs, azure-devops, devops

I have setup some service webhook events in TFS on-premise. When an event fails or couldn't respond on timely fashion the webhook goes on Enabled(Restricted) mode. Is there any way I can notify myself about the status change or about the failed events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to have a workaround to check the webhook and send out notifications if the webhook subscription is not enabled or the webhook service is down.

refer this:

> [Get TFS Webhook SubscriptionStatus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58492467/get-tfs-webhook-subscriptionstatus/58524371#58524371)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to set out notifications when a TFS Service Web hook event fails or there is any change in State of the web hook

Sorry for any inconvenience.

I am afraid there is no such out-of-the-box way to set out notifications when a TFS Service Web hook event fails.

You could add your request for this feature on our UserVoice site (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21 ), which is our main forum for product suggestions. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Leo. Posted a feature request. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/543845/notifications-when-a-webhook-subscription-status-c.html