# Get TFS Webhook SubscriptionStatus

Tags: azure, tfs, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

From my previous question [link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55732010/is-there-a-way-to-set-out-notifications-when-a-tfs-service-web-hook-event-fails) it appears that we do not have a feature in any version of TFS/Azure DevOps to setup monitoring for the webhook subscriptions.

As a workaround I'm now looking to write a PowerShell script to check the heartbeat of the subscription. From the Microsoft documentation [link here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/hooks/notifications/query?view=vsts-rest-tfs-4.1#subscription) it appears we can get the SubscriptionStatus by querying the subscription ID.

On a GET request for below API I receive all the details specified in the documentation but I'm unable to find "status" in the response.
Does anybody know if there is any other way to get the SubscriptionStatus.

> https://collectionurl/_apis/hooks/subscriptions/3d9af4ba-d642-4c80-8d62-34cabca322f9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that my API in question is correct, but for some reason i'm not getting 'enabled' status, I tested successfully for all other status mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/hooks/notifications/query?view=vsts-rest-tfs-4.1#subscriptionstatus).

I'm now setting up my PowerShell to execute every 5mins to check the webhook for its status and send an email for any other status than 'enabled'.

If the status is 'enabled' or 'empty' I further check consumerInputs.url to check if the webhook is alive.

This works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try listing the subscriptions instead:

`GET https://collectionurl/_apis/hooks/subscriptions?api-version=5.1`

You can filter the results using query parameters as follows:

`GET https://collectionurl/_apis/hooks/subscriptions?publisherId={publisherId}&eventType={eventType}&consumerId={consumerId}&consumerActionId={consumerActionId}&api-version=5.1`

You should see `status` there somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for responding. However it is not of much help, those APIs return same information as mine.